# Adding an external library in R package using Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I am trying to develop an R package which uses the [Sundials](http://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials-suite-nonlinear-differential-algebraic-equation-solvers) C library for solving differential equations. In order to not have the user install the library, I am putting the source code of the library in my package.

I have put all the header files from the library in `/inst/include/sundials-2.6.2` and the `.c` files in `src/sundials-2.6.2` of my package folder.

From my reading of the SO posts on this topic, `sourceCpp` of code in multiple files (e.g., separate `.h` and `.cpp` files should work if they are structured to be a part of the package. I am trying to run a example code file from the Sundials package

My code (only the beginning part) looks something like

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

#include "../inst/include/sundials-2.6.2/cvode/cvode.h"             /* prototypes for CVODE fcts., consts. */
#include "../inst/include/sundials-2.6.2/nvector/nvector_serial.h"  /* serial N_Vector types, fcts., macros */
#include "../inst/include/sundials-2.6.2/cvode/cvode_dense.h"      /* prototype for CVDense */
#include "../inst/include/sundials-2.6.2/sundials/sundials_dense.h" /* definitions DlsMat DENSE_ELEM */
#include "../inst/include/sundials-2.6.2/sundials/sundials_types.h" /* definition of type realtype */
```

But, I am getting an error

```
fatal error: sundials/sundials_nvector.h: No such file or directory
```

I do example of something similar done in the following github repositories

Rcppsundials - https://github.com/AleMorales/RcppSundials.R/blob/master/src/cvode.cpp

which calls the header files using

```
#include <cvodes/cvodes.h>           // CVODES functions and constants
#include <nvector/nvector_serial.h>  // Serial N_Vector
#include <cvodes/cvodes_dense.h>     // CVDense
```

and has incorporated the header files under the `/inst/include/` folder.

This is the first package I am trying to develop and I have not used C/C++ also extensively, so there could be something very silly in how I am trying to compile this program.

Just a side note - I was able to install and run an example on my OSX machine, but currently I am working from a Windows machine that does not have Sundials installed. It does have `Rtools` installed, so I can compile and run the example `Rcpp` programs.

Thank you
SN

Comment: Try adding `-I src/solver/` to your `PKG_CXXFLAGS` variable in `Makevars`, since you have `sundials/` in `src/solver/sundials/`.

Comment: @nrussell the repo he linked is a different project that he is using as a reference to write his own.

Comment: Ahhh. Missed that part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

External library linking should be done with the following setup:

```
R/
inst/
  |- include/
     |- sundials/ 
  |- header.h
src/
  |- sundials/
  |- Makevars
  |- Makevars.win
  |- action.cpp
man/
DESCRIPTION
NAMESPACE
```

Then add the following:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
PKG_CPPFLAGS =  -I../inst/include/ -I src/sundials
```

To both `Makevars` and `Makevars.win`

Here I've opted to remove the sundial version numbers from the folder names.

### Edit

I've made the fixes necessary to compile the package:

https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/pull/1

Note:

The structure was:

```
inst/
  |- include/
     |- sundials/  
        |- arkode/
        .....
        |- nvector/  
        |- sundials/ 
  |- header.h
```

This would have forced the include statements to be:

```
#include <sundials/cvodes/cvodes.h>           // CVODES functions and constants
#include <sundials/nvector/nvector_serial.h>  // Serial N_Vector
#include <sundials/cvodes/cvodes_dense.h>     // CVDense
```

I changed it so that:

```
inst/
  |- include/
     |- arkode/
     .....
     |- nvector/  
     |- sundials/ 
  |- header.h
```

So, the statements will always be:

```
#include <cvodes/cvodes.h>           // CVODES functions and constants
#include <nvector/nvector_serial.h>  // Serial N_Vector
#include <cvodes/cvodes_dense.h>     // CVDense
```

Comment: Thank you @Coatless and @nrussell. I added a `Makevars` and `Makevars.win` file in the `src` folder. I tried with both `#include <sundials/cvode.cvode.h>` and `#include "../inst/include/sundials/cvode/cvode.h" `(I changed the folder name to `sundials`). I am still getting the same error - `sundials_test.cpp:5:103: fatal error: ..inst/include/sundials/cvode/cvode.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Thank you @Coatless. Your suggestion worked on my OS X machine, I haven't tried it on Windows yet. I have posted code at - https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod/tree/master/src. The `/src/sundials_test.cpp` is not complete yet. I am getting a `C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations` error on `line 30` of the code (which is unrelated to this issue). The original complete code from the library that works on my OS X is at the gist - https://gist.github.com/sn248/b2e7726f609625df01f463715d5aa414. Hope you can help me in figuring out this error. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much @Coatless for the explanation and fixing the code. I will take a look at the pull request and carry on with trying to compile and run the example for the library.

Comment: Thank you @Coatless, with your help I was able to successfully `source` the `sundials_test.cpp` file. However, on running `load all` or `clean and rebuild` commands in `RStudio`, I am getting the error `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Rcppsbmod.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcppsbmod’`. Could you help me resolve this error? Thanks!

Comment: See my post here @SN248: http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-os-x/